# force a blue screen (from a simple driver bug?) in C code

Tags: c, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating a BlueScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667581/simulating-a-bluescreen)

Hello SO,

I'm trying to induce a BSOD somehow inline in my C code. My main background is Java but have been fortunate to have been tutored by some coworkers and am helping out with a simple C utility.

There's two sections:
1) write to a hard drive (I finished this, wasn't too bad)
2) Force a blue screen immediately after sending the last SCSI write command

You can probably tell the intent of the program easily now.

I've tried two things so far:
1) Externally calling pskill.exe (windows utility) to manually crash csrss.exe which forces a blue screen every time since csrss.exe is a required service of windows. This doesn't work because it's not fast enough. The call to the external utility takes too long so we need inline code to compile with the write to disk section in order to crash the computer fast enough.

2) Use the windows.h API to call TerminateProcess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
The problem is this function cannot end system related tasks so it can't close csrss.exe

This has left me short on options. I need a clever way to kill csrss.exe in our own native code without an external call or a clever way to force a blue screen in internal code OR I need a very simple driver I can load and call which will blue screen the machine immediately. Could be as short as 1 line calling KeBugCheck http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551948.aspx

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: I'm a bit dense right now, so, can you explain the intent of the program?

Comment: I'd guess that OP is developing a tool to test resilience of hardware to kernel stops.

Comment: the intent is to check storage cache speed and integrity.

Comment: In that case it may be interesting to use a Remote Power Switch.

Comment: we are attacking this from two angles: software and hardware. eventually there will be a hardware solution as well to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to write a trivial driver that calls [`KeBugCheck()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551948.aspx) as you yourself suggest. You can take the most simple example from the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) and cut it down to the barebones.

Comment: a link to this 'ddk' would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: It's now called Windows Driver Kit, I've added a link, any websearch engine would have taken you there too.

Answer (score 2):

I recomment [Not My Fault](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/Notmyfault.zip) from sysinternals.

Comment: Just downloaded it now I will check it out. thanks.

Comment: There seems like a lot of code in here. Speed is of the essence so stripping it down would be a challenge with my limited C knowledge. I'll keep it as something to fall back on.

Comment: May be a lot of code but I don't see any reason why it would necessarily be too slow for your needs. It's only the performance of the path that provokes the STOP that matters. My guess is that most of the other code would not run when you actioned a STOP.

Comment: good point. I will take a second look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to get a blue screen when running in kernel mode:

1. Dereference a null pointer, or
2. Divide by zero

Comment: And use the result of that (for example, print it somewhere) to avoid the compiler optimizing it away.

Comment: Divide by zero causes a STOP in kernel mode? Really? Anyway, there is a dedicated function to provoke a STOP. OP's problem appears to be that he doesn't have any code that runs in kernel mode yet.

Comment: I know how to do both of these but am unsure how to go about getting in 'kernel' mode and my coworkers have told me it's quite hard to write a driver so I was looking for a simple one I could load whose only purpose is to BSOD.

Comment: You're right -- I read the question as if OP was already running in the kernel. The driver skeleton with a bug check is the most straight-forward approach.